# countdown timer in android

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I have a table with some values and I want to do update the UI(values) every 10 seconds. and I want to show a countdown timer to the user to know what is going to happen...
but it crashes.
the code I used for that is shown below:

```
tv2_r7= (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView2_r7);

    final Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        int i = 10;
        public void run() {
            tv2_r7.setText(String.valueOf(i));
            i--;
            if (i< 0)
                timer.cancel();
        }
    }, 0, 1000);
```

it works well in simple java app when I have `System.out.println(i--);` instead of `tv2_r7.setText(String.valueOf(i));
                i--;`

Comment: Use Android's timer: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have updated the UI value in timer which is wrong. YOu need to use

> runOnUIThread

method there.

```
tv2_r7 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView2_r7);

    final Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask()
    {
        int i = 10;

        public void run()
        {
            runOnUIThread(new Runnable()
            {

                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    tv2_r7.setText(String.valueOf(i));

                }
            });

            i--;
            if (i < 0)
                timer.cancel();
        }
    }, 0, 1000);
}
```